# how can I reference the position of a row when a condition is met in a csv file

Tags: python

I am trying to perform one hot encoding on my csv file. For refrence here are some values in my csv file:

```
label,md5,create new key via CryptAcquireContext,delete user account group ......... so on ....
malware,0e498d2283a99aad9a997200caf2f24e,packed with UPX,delete user account group
malware,1f0ffe101843e4135af712d899b0c0d3,inspect load icon resource,reference analysis tools strings
```

I was planning to convert these values to integers except hash and convert malware to 1.

I was planning on checking to see if there was a match (after 2nd column) and convert to one if there was ad to 0 if not.

I was successfully able to convert all malware/benign to integers since it was a static value:

```py
import csv
f = open('onehot.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)

with open('cleaned_features-test-2.csv') as csv_file_obj:
      
    # Skips the heading
    # Using next() method
    heading = next(csv_file_obj)
      
    # Create reader object by passing the file 
    # object to reader method
    reader_obj = csv.reader(csv_file_obj)
      
    # Iterate over each row in the csv file 
    # using reader object
    for row in reader_obj:
        if (row[0]) == 'malware':
            row[0] = '1'
        else:
            row[0] = '0'
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This code worked fine since I knew where the malware was however how can I find a way to achieve this where I do not know where the match occours as  its quite random since I want to convert matches to 1s
Here is what I came up with:

```py
headers = []
updated_data = []
output_file = "output.csv"

# Read the headers from the text file
with open("feature-list.txt", 'r') as txt_file:
    for line in txt_file:
        line = line.strip()  # Remove trailing newline characters
        headers.append(line)

import csv
f = open('onehot.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)

# Open file
with open('cleaned_features-test-2.csv') as csv_file_obj:
      
    # Skips the heading
    # Using next() method
    heading = next(csv_file_obj)
      
    # Create reader object by passing the file 
    # object to reader method
    reader_obj = csv.reader(csv_file_obj)
      
    # Iterate over each row in the csv file 
    # using reader object
    for row in reader_obj:
        if (row[2::]) in headers:
            #than that row column should be 1
        else:
            row[0] = '0'
        writer.writerow(row)
```

The issue is the code does not change for example delete user account group to 1 even though its explicitly in headers:label,md5,create new key via CryptAcquireContext,delete user account group ......... so on ....

```py
headers = ['create new key via CryptAcquireContext', 'delete user account group', 'send file via HTTP', 'send data', 'stop service', 'encrypt data using DES via WinAPI', 'suspend thread', 'get file size', 'encrypt data using RC4 via WinAPI', 'hash data via WinCrypt', 'inject dll', 'get COMSPEC environment variable', 'download URL', 'install driver', 'get token membership', 'delete directory', .......]

[img][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpFV9.png
```

Comment: `I do not know where the match occours as its quite random`: could you be more explicit? Does 'malware' apear in another column, or... ? And what's wrong with your 2nd code?

Comment: sure :) , I will edit my post

Comment: Are the values in `headers` column names or column values or both?  How do you determine if a cell in your output should be coded `1` or `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it occurs in different rows (unclear from the asked question), you can just replace it:

```py
for row in reader_obj:
    row = [x.replace("malware", "1").replace("benign", "0") for x in row]
    # do something with replaced row data
```

EDIT: if you need an `int` instead of `str`, you can cast the x value inside the list as `int(x....)`

EDIT #2: I think I figured out what your question is. Try this:

```py
with open("file.csv") as csv_file_obj:
    heading = next(csv_file_obj).strip().split(",")
    reader_obj = csv.reader(csv_file_obj)

    for row in reader_obj:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            # Make sure that we skip the first 2 columns
            if i < 2:
                continue
            if row[i] == heading[i]:
                row[i] = 1
            else:
                row[i] = 0
```

HEADERS:

```py
['label', 'md5', 'create new key via CryptAcquireContext', 'delete user account group']
```

INPUT:

```py
['malware', '0e498d2283a99aad9a997200caf2f24e', 'packed with UPX', 'delete user account group']
['malware', '1f0ffe101843e4135af712d899b0c0d3', 'inspect load icon resource', 'reference analysis tools strings']
['benign', '1f0ffe101843e4135af712d899b0c0d3', 'inspect load icon resource', 'reference analysis tools strings']
```

OUTPUT:

```py
['malware', '0e498d2283a99aad9a997200caf2f24e', 0, 1]
['malware', '1f0ffe101843e4135af712d899b0c0d3', 0, 0]
['benign', '1f0ffe101843e4135af712d899b0c0d3', 0, 0]
```

Comment: hi sir , I was hoping to convert features to 1 or 0 if they are in my headers list

Comment: @jack_dan check the edited post

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I interpret what you are seeking to do. If this is not correct, please feel free to add more details.

Given a list of "hot values"

```py
hot_values = [
    "malware",
    "create new key via CryptAcquireContext",
    "delete user account group",
    #...
]
```

you want to search the actual values in all cells of your csv and replace the actual values with either `1` or `0` depending on if that actual value is in the list of hot values:

```py
with open('cleaned_features-test-2.csv', 'r') as file_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_in)
    with open('onehot.csv', 'w') as file_out:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            for key, value in row.items():
                if key == "md5":
                    continue
                row[key] = int(value in hot_values)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Given a test CSV like:

```
label,md5,create new key via CryptAcquireContext,delete user account group
malware,0e498d2283a99aad9a997200caf2f24e,packed with UPX,delete user account group
malware,1f0ffe101843e4135af712d899b0c0d3,inspect load icon resource,reference analysis tools strings
```

That should produce a resulting csv:

```
label,md5,create new key via CryptAcquireContext,delete user account group
1,0e498d2283a99aad9a997200caf2f24e,0,1
1,1f0ffe101843e4135af712d899b0c0d3,0,0
```

Comment: I also understood it in a similar fashion, except my answer tries to match by position too. The way the question is asked is very weird/incomplete

Comment: @Vojko Ya, I'm not actually sure if "hot values" represents cell values or column names :-)

Comment: @Vojko forgive me I am new. I was hoping to do to put 1 if value exists and 0 if it doesnt.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpFV9.png this img will help as it will put a 1 and 0s for all other values